# why query get inserted twice in database, Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I am trying to insert `$pindata` array in database in function `pin/add`, then send user redirect to send function of Mail Controller, to just send verification email to the registered user, the `$pindata` array get inserted successfully and when it redirected to mail/send function the send function insert $pindata array to the database also which makes two records with the same data inserted to databse (duplicate record), i tried to debug and i end up with 
`$this->email->send();` this line is inserting `$pindata` again to database. any help will be appreciated, and thanks in advance. Plz follow the link `http://localhost/addypin/user/add` .

***In  user Controller***

```
class User extends MY_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

function index() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}

function add() {
    // get email from HTML form.
    $id = 0;

    $data = array(
        'email'     => 'a.ali2010@yahoo.com',
        'url'       => $this->createUserUrl() . '.addypin.com',
        'pinscount' => 0,
        'type'      => 'personal'
    );

    $this->user_m->login($data);

    $user = $this->user_m->get_by(array('email'=> $data['email']), TRUE);

    if($user) {
        foreach ($user as $foundeduser) {
            if($foundeduser->pinscount == 5 && $foundeduser->type == 'personal') {
                die('Sorry, You have reached the maximum pins number as Personal Account.');
            } else if($foundeduser->pinscount == 20 && $foundeduser->type == 'corporate') {
                die('Sorry, You have reached the maximum pins number as Corporate Account.');
            } else {
                $data['pinscount'] = $foundeduser->pinscount;
                $data['id'] = $foundeduser->id;
                $this->user_m->login($data);    
                redirect('pin/add');
            }
        }           
    } else {
        $id = $this->user_m->save($data);
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->user_m->login($data);
        redirect('pin/add');
    }
}

function getPinsCount() {
    return $this->user_m->getPinsCount();

}

function createUserUrl() {
    return $this->user_m->createUserUrl();
}

function checksession() {
    if($this->user_m->checksession()) {
        echo 'expired';
    } else {
        echo 'NotExpired';
    }
}
```

}

***mail controller***

```
class Mail extends Frontend_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->model('pin_m');
    $this->load->model('user_m');
}

function index() {
    // this function for test only.
    echo "hi";
}

function send() {
    $confCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('addyourpin@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to('a.ali2010.fci@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email test');
    $this->email->message('Hi User thanks for registration, click the link below to activate your account '. anchor("http://localhost/addypin/mail/verify/".$confCode, 'Activate Account'));
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo "Email was sent successufly";          
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

    redirect('mail/demo');
}

function verify() {
    $confCode = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array(
        'confirmationcode' => $confCode 
    );

    $pin = $this->pin_m->get_by($data, TRUE);
    if($pin) {
        foreach ($pin as $row) {
            if($confCode === $row->confirmationcode) {
                $registerTime = $row->regtime;
                $oneWeekLater = $registerTime + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                if(time() > $oneWeekLater) {
                    // Confirmation expires.
                    die('Registration date more than one week later Failed');
                } else {
                    // Confirmation done.
                    $active = array('active' => 1);
                    $this->pin_m->save($active, $row->id);
                    $this->user_m->save(array('pinscount' => $this->user_m->getPinsCount() + 1), $this->session->userdata('id'));
                    redirect('pin/');
                }
            } 
            // confirmation code not match the one in the database.
            else die('False confirmation code');
        }
    }

}

function demo() {
    echo 'One click to go, verify your account.';
}
```

}

***Pin controller***

```
class Pin extends MY_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('pin_m');
}

function index() {
    echo "Hi again";
}

function add() {
    $confCode = random_str();
    $pindata = array(
        'name'                  => 'My home', 
        'location'              => 'Cairo',
        'code'                  => 'SDSDSD',
        'postalcode'            => '123321',
        'active'                => 0,
        'user_id'               => $this->session->userdata('id'),
        'confirmationcode'      => $confCode,
        'latLang'               => '',
        'regtime'               => time()
    );

    $this->pin_m->save($pindata);
    redirect('mail/send/'. $confCode);
}

function edit() {
    $data = $this->pin_m->get(9);
    echo print_r($data);

}

function share() {

}

function delete() {

}
```

}

***In Model***

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
protected $_table_name = '';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by;
protected $_timestamps = FALSE;
public $rules = array();

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE) {
    if($id === NULL) {
        $method = 'result';
    } else if($single === TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    } else {
        // filter id for security issues
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);         
        $method = 'row';
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();       
}

public function get_by($data, $single = FALSE) {
    $this->db->where($data);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL) {
    // insert
    if($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // update
    else {
        // filter id for security issues
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);

        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }
    return $id;
}

public function delete($id) {
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);

    if(!$id) return FALSE;

    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    if($this->db->delete($this->_table_name))
        return TRUE;
}

private function filter($id) {
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);
    return $id;
}
```

}

Comment: Paste code of `demo` function also !!

Comment: also add model function.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i added the whole model check now

Comment: @Saty i added the demo function

Comment: add this..  just a try $this->pin_m->save($pindata,$pindata['user_id']);

Comment: @BipinKareparambil if i will pass id save function will make update not insert and in case of no data in pin table in the database it will give error

Comment: this is the first url i hit in the browser track it plz
http://localhost/addypin/user/add

Comment: here you want to do update.. right?

Comment: nop i wanna insert not update

Comment: @BipinKareparambil plz i debug the whole project and i end up with that the function send of email library makes the problem here
$this->email->send() insert pindata array again

Answer (score 0):

Include this

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

By default it is ***Plain Text***

In Model

```
public function save($data) {

    $id = $data['user_id'];
    $data1 = array(
           'name'               => $data['name'],
           'location'           => $data['location'],
           'code'               => $data['code'],
           'postalcode'         => $data['postalcode'],
           'active'             => $data['active'],
           'confirmationcode'   => $data['confirmationcode'],
           'latLang'            => $data['latLang'],
           'regtime'            => $data['regtime'],
        );


    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_name', $data1); 
}
```

You are passing one value to model `$this->pin_m->save($pindata);`. But in model you catch two `public function save($data, $id = NULL) {`

Comment: i added the model function save();

Comment: it is only one function for update and insert based on the id
if passed the id it will make update and if not it will make insert 
where two save function u meant abdulla ??

Comment: i tried it for many situation and it works fine and also tried to make to function for save and insert and also i get the same problem here

Comment: @BipinKareparambil i added the whole model

Comment: no it wont be(use `save()` method which i provided). there is some other method inserting the data.

Comment: where is the demo() function?

Comment: it is only function for test
function demo() {
  echo 'One click to go, verify your account.';
 }

Comment: i added the demo function

Comment: What is the URL in your browser after doing all these operation?

Comment: Change the variable name $data in your model to something else.. like: $data_array

Comment: @BipinKareparambil i will give u the whole story from the beginning i will edit my question right now 
the url is http://localhost/addypin/user/add 
i will edit my question to see the whole story

Comment: @BipinKareparambil i edited the whole question take a look now

Comment: add this.. just a try $this->pin_m->save($pindata,$pindata['user_id']);

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public function save($data) {

$id = $data['user_id'];
$data_array = array(
       'name'               => $data['name'],
       'location'           => $data['location'],
       'code'               => $data['code'],
       'postalcode'         => $data['postalcode'],
       'active'             => $data['active'],
       'confirmationcode'   => $data['confirmationcode'],
       'latLang'            => $data['latLang'],
       'regtime'            => $data['regtime'],
    );


$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('table_name', $data_array);
```

}